# How to format DateTime.now().toIso8601String()

Tags: flutter

I understand how to format the regular `DateTime.now()` with `${DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd().format(addTimeHere)}` and for `toIso8601String()`. I'm probably using it wrong. But when I'm using `DateTime.now().toIso8601String()` it shows the full time **2019-12-03T17:50:23.476164** which I understand that's what the `toIso8601String()` is but how to it get it to show like **1:22 PM** instead of the entire **2019-12-03T17:50:23.476164**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nokia3310, I am not aware of any built-in function that can convert Iso8601String() to local time, so i think you need to deserialize your `DateTime.now().toIso8601String()`. You can use [build_value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) package to deserialize. And here's how you can get just the local time,

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Test'),
            ),
            body: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(new DateFormat.jm().format(DateTime.parse(getTime().toString()).toLocal()), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                  )
            )
            ));
  }

  getTime() {
    var serializers =
    (Serializers().toBuilder()..add(Iso8601DateTimeSerializer())).build();// Instantiate serializer for Iso8601
    var serialized = DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
    var specifiedType = const FullType(DateTime);
    return serializers.deserialize(serialized, specifiedType: specifiedType);
  }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Hope this helps.

Comment: i liked your answers with visual answers, i like the way you explain with image. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, glad it was helpful.

Answer (score -2):

```
DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd().format(DateTime.now())
```

Comment: make sure to explain why this is the right answer, and not a one line of code.